# Open folder as android studio project

Tags: android-studio, project, right-click, windows-explorer

How to add "Open folder as Android Studio project" to folders (in file explorer in windows) quick menu (right click).

[image: screenshot with that option for IntelliJ Idea]

Comment: Why nobody has an answer ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open windows registry by pressing Window + r  type regedit and enter
Run the registry editor
Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
Right click on shell create a new key and name it as you want to see the entry in context menu
then right click on the created file and create a new key and name it as command in lower case
Click command and on right side pane you will see a key named as default
Double click the default entry and enter the path of application exe file as the value.
You need enter a spacebar then %1 at the end of application path that you entered as a value of default value.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I Tried your solution , this only open Android Studio but not open the selected folder in android studio window

Comment: You need enter %1 at the end of application path that you entered as a value of default value.
its working fine for me.
let me know in case it doesnt work

Comment: Thanks   Haseeb Sajjad , it worked for me too  after separating the path and %1 with a space

Comment: It works but after every Android Studio update you will need to manually update .exe path.

Comment: Remember, Default String value in the first key you create and name will be the text you'll see in the context menu, so change it similar to "Open Folder as Android Studio Project" and You can also create a new String value in this key, name it icon and set its value to Android Studio's exe path without quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps Haseeb Sajjad's answer didn't work for everyone. Try this in Sep 2022.
[Under Shell create a new key called Android Studio. The '(default)' key that was created can be named anything you want to see in the options when you right click a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdBER.png)

[image: While still in Android Studio folder, right click and create a new string and add the path to your Android Studio '.exe' file as in picture 3]

[image: Here you add the path to your Android Studio '.exe' file]

[image: Right click on the Android Studio folder and add a new key and add the path to your '.exe' file]

Answer (score 2):

Just save this as a .cmd file and run. Be sure to change the path to your android studio installation path.

```
        @echo off

    :: change the path below to match your installed version
    SET AndroidStudioPath=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe
     
    echo Adding file entries
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\AndroidStudio" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with AndroidStudio"   /f
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\AndroidStudio" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%AndroidStudioPath%,0" /f
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\AndroidStudio\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%AndroidStudioPath% \"%%1\"" /f
     
    echo Adding within a folder entries
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\AndroidStudio" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with AndroidStudio"   /f
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\AndroidStudio" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%AndroidStudioPath%,0" /f
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\AndroidStudio\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%AndroidStudioPath% \"%%V\"" /f

    echo Adding folder entries
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AndroidStudio" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with AndroidStudio"   /f
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AndroidStudio" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%AndroidStudioPath%,0" /f
    @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AndroidStudio\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%AndroidStudioPath% \"%%1\"" /f

    pause
```

[Here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/kumaran-IV0IV/9eaee2987934df1244765441dc36e5e6#file-open-with-android-studio-cmd)

Comment: make sure to run this command as administrator